# Automatic e-mail with changes in the body - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have to create a VBA to send automatic e-mails (the body of the e-mail links the recipient to a specific project that he is responsible for). The problem that I encountered is the fact that a certain recipient (i.e. placed in "TO") can be responsible for more tasks. The VBA that I am using sends emails to each task (even if the person is responsible for more). What can I do to count through recipients, if it's greater than 1 to send the e-mail which includes all of the tasks. I really need your help.

```
<PRE>Sub SendEMail()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Ebody As String
lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastRow
Ebody = "<FONT SIZE = 4 name = Arial>" & "Dear " & Cells(i, "A").Value          
& "<br>" _
& "<br>" _
& "Please note that the below mentioned projectd are in scope for reporting." & "<br>" _
& "<br>" _
& Cells(i, "C").Value & " - " & Cells(i, "E").Value & "<br>" _
& "xxxxx will investigate and action your notification according to priority and to ensure public safety." & "<br>" _
& "For further information, please phone xxxxx on 6111 and quote reference number:" & "<br>" _
& "Your original report can be seen below:" & "</Font>" & "<br>" _
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
.To = Cells(i, "B").Value
.Cc = Cells(i, "D").Value
.Subject = "Your Registration Code"
.HtmlBody = Ebody
.Attachments.Add "C:\Test\Document.docx"
.Attachments.Add "C:\Test\Document1.docx"
.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Financial@yahoo.com"
.Display
End With
Next
End Sub </pre>
```

Comment: What I have done in this instance, is to restructure the data such that each row denotes 1 email, if there are duplicate emails, I add the extra task into the cell and separate the data by commas. Then I do instr(",", cell)> 0, then I pace the tasks into an array and then loop through them into the email before I send.

Comment: Thank you so much. It would be really useful if you could help me with the code.

Comment: Okay but am I understanding your problem correctly?

Comment: The current table structure: 1st Column: e-mail address, 2nd Column: Project number (i.e. task), 3rd Column: Project Name. There are cases when the e-mail address is duplicate. In that situation the VBA has to send only one e-mail for the respective projects (i.e. second column). The project numbers and project name have to be inserted in the body of the e-mail on separate lines (i.e. like bullet point).

Comment: Yeah so you will need to create an additional column which will be blank if the row was not a duplicate, while if it is not blank then it should contain the two projects with a comma separating these values.

Comment: And which would be the code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Emailer()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range, y, sbody
    Dim eml As Worksheet, bd As Worksheet
    Dim underlyingary, ISINarray, Accountarray, i

    Set eml = Sheets("Emailer"): Set bd = Sheets("Body"): Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each y In eml.Range("A2:A" & eml.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row)

    If eml.Range("F" & y.Row) <> "" Then
        underlyingary = Split(eml.Range("F" & y.Row), ",")
        Accountarray = Split(eml.Range("G" & y.Row), ",")
        ISINarray = Split(eml.Range("H" & y.Row), ",")
            For i = 0 To UBound(underlyingary)
                sbody = sbody & vbNewLine & "Underlying: " & WorksheetFunction.Proper(Trim(underlyingary(i))) & " Account Number: " & WorksheetFunction.Proper(Trim(Accountarray(i))) & " ISIN: " & WorksheetFunction.Proper(Trim(ISINarray(i))) & "<br>" & "<br>"
            Next i
    Else
            sbody = sbody & vbNewLine & "Underlying: " & WorksheetFunction.Proper(Trim(eml.Range("C" & y.Row))) & " Account Number: " & WorksheetFunction.Proper(Trim(eml.Range("D" & y.Row))) & " ISIN: " & WorksheetFunction.Proper(Trim(eml.Range("E" & y.Row))) & "<br>"
    End If

    On Error GoTo cleanup
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = eml.Range("A" & y.Row)
                .Subject = bd.Range("B2")
                .cc = eml.Range("I" & y.Row)
                .htmlBody = bd.Range("A2") _
                    & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                        bd.Range("A3") & _
                        Trim(eml.Range("B" & y.Row)) & _
                        bd.Range("A4") _
                    & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                        sbody _
                    & "<br>" & _
                        bd.Range("A5") _
                    & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<li>" & _
                        bd.Range("A6").Text & "</li>" & _
                     "<br>" & "<br>" & "<li>" & _
                        bd.Range("A7").Text & "</li>" & _
                     "<br>" & "<br>" & "<li>" & _
                        bd.Range("A8").Text & "</li>" & _
                     "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                        bd.Range("A9") _
                    & "<br>" & bd.Range("A10")
                .display
            End With

            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
    Next y
cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that there are some intricacies here, first I had an email sheet and a body sheet (just to make it easier to update later). I had the data structured as above.

Comment: So the body of the e-mail has to be inserted into another sheet - "Body"?

Comment: At your convenience, just change the code if you like. I think you had some good html code in your code, so I would keep that, I would just add in the sbody somewhere that worked with your previous code. I just made a different sheet called body, because if someone else wanted to change the body with no vba skills, they could.

Comment: Quick question: when running the code provided by you there are 3 bullet points appear and I don't exactly know what line of the code corresponds to them; Also - has to be inserted for each row? <pre> bd.Range("A8").Text & "</li>" & _
                     "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                        bd.Range("A9") _
                    & "<br>" & bd.Range("A10")</pre>

Comment: So the <li></li> is giving the bullet points, something I needed to do for the code I was using.  you can remove any of the lines in the .htmlbody part

Comment: One more question: how should I build the Excel file in terms of columns? Thank again a lot for your patience.

Comment: Whatever letter is in the range here - eml.Range("A" & y.Row) - denotes the column it should in in, for instance eml.Range("A" & y.Row) is column A, the email. you would need to review this and keep on displaying the email until you get it right.